# MQTT and ActiveMQ communication

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, mqtt

### Background

I am very new to MQTT and ActiveMQ. I am trying to learn about both technologies, but their integration using Node.js is not clear.

### Objective

The objective here would be to use MQTT with node, and then use ActiveMQ's broker.

### Questions

1. If I publish a message on a MQTT topic then how I can transfer that message to an ActiveMQ queue?
2. If I have a MQTT topic named "Foo", does ActiveMQ need to have a queue named "Foo"?
3. Does Node.js support the MQTT protocol?
4. After publishing a message in a MQTT topic with content "Foo" using Node.js, how I can retrieve it from an ActiveMQ queue?

### EDIT

My MQTT is running on a different server so I have added the below `activemq.xml` file. However, after adding it activemq gives me the following error on startup:

```
<transportConnectors>
<transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="tcp://<myhostname>:1883?      maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

So how can I get the message published on MQTT topic in activemq queue?
Do I need any other configuration or do I need to first subscribe to a MQTT topic using java or any other technology and then push that message on ActiveMQ queue? Or ActiveMQ it does automatically?

Answer (score 0):

1. By using compositeTopic in ActiveMQ configuration (activemq.xml).
2. No, ActiveMQ has a topic named FOO used by MQTT.
3. No, but there are extensions to Node.js which supports MQTT.
4. By using compositeTopic (see #1).

Comment: Thank You, Petter. But what configuration I need means I need to add my MQTT host to activemq.xml under <transportConnectors>..</transportConnectors> and activemq automatically listens messages from MQTT topic.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "My MQTT is running on different server"?

1. If you want a clustered things, you should use networkConnector instead of transportConnector.
2. If you want ActiveMQ to accept MQTT connection, simply change the protocol from `uri="tcp://<myhostname>:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"` to `"mqtt://<myhostname>:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"`